# Cant start application using .bat file but can stop application

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file program like this

```
taskkill /f /im LearnBatV1.0.0.exe
timeout /t 1
start K:\POST\Govind\My Actual Work\LearnBat\LearnBatV1.0.0.exe
exit
```

LearnBatV1.0.0 is a simple application I created. I run the application and then I run the bat file. Then the bat file will execute the first two lines which will stop and close the application. But then when the third line tries to execut, it shows an error

```
K: \ POST \ Govind \ My Actual Work \ LearnBat \ LearnBatV1.0.0.exe  could not be found. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try 
again.
```

How is that it is correctly able to stop and close the application in the first line but not in the third line. The address is 100% correct. Then why is it giving an error. Kindly help me. Thank you.

Comment: don’t miss the pair of double quotes between `start` and `”path\program”`, they are supposed to hold the cmd window title

Comment: than you, the double quotes between the start and path file worked and it stopped and restarted the program. Thank you.

Comment: Please be aware that there is no guarantee the `taskkill.exe`, even with the `/f` option, _(which should generally not be used)_, will have completed the termination of that 'task' before it attempts to reopen it. You have simply assumed that `1` second will be sufficient, but have no real way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LoopCount=6"
set "ForceKill="

:EndProgramLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq LearnBatV1.0.0.exe" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "LearnBatV1.0.0.exe" >nul || goto StartProgram
set /A LoopCount-=1
if %LoopCount% == 0 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to terminate LearnBatV1.0.0.exe!
    echo/
    pause
    goto EndBatch
)
if %LoopCount% == 1 set "ForceKill=/F "
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM LearnBatV1.0.0.exe %ForceKill%>nul 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
goto EndProgramLoop

:StartProgram
start "" "K:\POST\Govind\My Actual Work\LearnBat\LearnBatV1.0.0.exe"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The batch file checks first if `LearnBatV1.0.0.exe` is running at all. It starts the executable if that is not the case.

The first argument string enclosed in `"` is interpreted as title string for the console window even if the started executable is a Windows GUI window and so no console window is opened at all. For that reason `""` is used to define an empty title string. The fully qualified file name of the executable is enclosed in `"` as required because of the space character, too. I recommend to use a meaningful title string if the executable is a Windows GUI application.

I hope, your program is coded to work with any directory as current directory as the current directory for `LearnBatV1.0.0.exe` is defined by the process starting `cmd.exe` to process this batch file and can be any directory for that reason.

But if `LearnBatV1.0.0.exe` is really running, there is first decremented by one an environment variable counting how often the loop to end the program is executed already with leaving the loop with an error message if it is not possible to get `LearnBatV1.0.0.exe` either gracefully self-terminated or finally brutally killed by the operating system.

There is tried four times to send the [WM_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) message via **TASKKILL** to all the running processes `LearnBatV1.0.0.exe` which should result in a graceful self-termination of the executable on not being very bad coded. There is used finally the option `/F` to force a brutal kill of the process by the operating system as last attempt.

There is made a delay of one second between each **TASKKILL** and **TASKLIST** execution to give the process the time it perhaps needs to gracefully terminate itself.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `|` and `>nul` and `2>nul` and [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of conditional execution operator `||`.